# jquery start working by pressing f12 button?

Tags: jquery, css

I am working on the jQuery scrollbar to change the layout of the scroll bar horizontally, but when I press the F12 button the scroll starts working and when I close the firebug the scroll is still working. But when I refresh the page it stops and moves to the right side and becomes disabled.

I'm using:

```
advanced: {
    updateOnContentResize: true,
    updateOnBrowserResize: true
}
```

**script**

```
 $(window).load(function () {
     $("#divMain2").slickscroll({
         horizontalScroll: true,
         scrollButtons: {
             enable: true
         },
     });
 });
```

but is useless. Any hints about this issue?

Comment: Can you provide fiddler code?

Comment: are you calling your scripts on window resize?? when you load Developer Tools or Firebug, that actually resizes the window and will trigger any events which are set to fire on resize. You should also call the events you want on `load`.

Comment: no i am just writing it in the function.

Comment: We're going to need to see more code or a fiddle as @monu suggested.

Comment: i added my javascript function in above edits

Comment: plz now check the code

Comment: Which `slickscroll` plugin is this? Googling for it, I find at least three and none of them have options for `horizontalScroll` or `scrollButtons`. Please provide a url for the plugin.

Comment: can you create fiddle?????/

Comment: what is advanced: {} here???????